# how can I do swagger documentation on req.query and req.param in ExpressJS

Tags: node.js

someone can help me on how to do documentation in swagger.I have done much on the crud requests documentation and i need to know how i can show frontend the specifications either req.body req.query or req.params need to be passed

Comment: First, show what packages you already use and code how you use and configure them.

Comment: thanks for your reply ,,,,I think I just fixed  the problem ,,,,thanks for your concern buddy!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.